# Laravel eager loading Postgres

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I'm using postgres DB and I don't know how to eager loading a model with Laravel, maybe is not supported with postgres??

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  X does not exist

```
$company->operators
```

Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...elect * from "operator" where "operator"."companyid" in (76)

Laravel uses Where IN

Comment: Post some code!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PostgreSQL: ERROR: operator does not exist: integer = character varying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23622993/postgresql-error-operator-does-not-exist-integer-character-varying)