# Can we use JDBC to write data from postgresql to Spark?

Tags: r, postgresql, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load my tables on PostgreSQL to Spark.
I have successfully read the table from PostgreSQL to Spark using jdbc.
I have a code written in R, which I want to use on the table, but I cannot access the data in R.

using the following code to connect

```
 val pgDF_table = spark.read
                          .format("jdbc")
                          .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
                          .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://10.128.0.4:5432/sparkDB")
                          .option("dbtable", "survey_results")
                          .option("user", "prashant")
                          .option("password","pandey")
                          .load()
    pgDF_table.show
```

is there any option as spark.write?

Comment: You may find https://spark.rstudio.com helpful. It allows you to define Spark jobs directly from R, rather than Scala, and bring data from Spark into R for further processing.

Comment: but my data is in postgresql, there's nothing related to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SparkR,

> You can [read](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/R/read.jdbc.html) data from JDBC using the following code:

```
read.jdbc(url, tableName, partitionColumn = NULL, lowerBound = NULL,
  upperBound = NULL, numPartitions = 0L, predicates = list(), ...)
```

**Arguments**

```
`url':  JDBC database url of the form 'jdbc:subprotocol:subname'

`tableName':    the name of the table in the external database

`partitionColumn':  the name of a column of integral type that will be used for partitioning

`lowerBound':   the minimum value of 'partitionColumn' used to decide partition stride

`upperBound':   the maximum value of 'partitionColumn' used to decide partition stride

`numPartitions':    the number of partitions, This, along with 'lowerBound' (inclusive), 'upperBound' (exclusive), form partition strides for generated WHERE clause expressions used to split the column 'partitionColumn' evenly. This defaults to SparkContext.defaultParallelism when unset.

`predicates':   a list of conditions in the where clause; each one defines one partition
```

> Data can be [written](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/R/write.jdbc.html) to JDBC using the following code:

```
write.jdbc(x, url, tableName, mode = "error", ...)
```

**Arguments**

```
`x`: a SparkDataFrame.

`url`: JDBC database url of the form jdbc:subprotocol:subname.

`tableName`: yhe name of the table in the external database.

`mode`: one of 'append', 'overwrite', 'error', 'ignore' save mode (it is 'error' by default).

`...`: additional JDBC database connection properties.
```

**JDBC Driver must be in spark classpath**

Comment: using jdbc gives me following error: Error: Error in jdbc : java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver ERROR RBackendHandler: jdbc on 16 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: add postgresql jdbc driver in classpath. https://www.dataxone.com/import-export-postgresql-data-sparkr-dataframe/

Comment: after adding the path successcully, i get the following error when reading the file: ```ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.````

Comment: so any idea how we can define the type cast explicitly in predicates?

Comment: @VasudhaJain: i guess you are trying to compare integer with varchar. check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/25358092/5019163

Comment: Thanks, Bob, I figured it out and sorted it.